# How to hide the action button in Vega

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I use vega-react and I would like to know the easiest way not to display the "Actions" button on the chart.

[image]

if I declare all actions to be false it will not display any actions but the button will still be present.

```
<Vega spec={spec as VisualizationSpec} data={barData} actions={{
                   export: false,
                   source: false,
                   compiled: false,
                   editor: false,
               }}  />
```

Comment: What if you provide `actions={false}`, this should simply remove all the actions right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [vega-embed](https://github.com/vega/vega-embed) documentation, the `actions` setting can either be an object or a Boolean, and relevant to your question:

> If the value is `true`, all action links will be shown and none if the value is `false`

So I believe what you want is `actions=false`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, set `actions: false`, however what I didnt realise is that this has to be in the third parameter of the `vegaEmbed` function

```js
vegaEmbed(
  '#vegaChart_traders', 
  yourVlSpec, 
  {renderer: "svg", actions: false}
);
```

rather than in the `yourVlSpec` object

hope that helps someone :)